# Weird jsp behaviour

Tags: java, jsp

I stumbled upon a problem dealing with jsps.
Even though the second cout `<c:out value="" />` should display nothing it displays the cout above it, so 'Text'. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="html" uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="forms" uri="http://www.common-controls.com/cc/tags-forms"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt"%>

<html:form action="/rulesDetail">
  <forms:form type="edit" formid="rulesDetail">
    <forms:section title="Title">
       <forms:row>
          <forms:plaintext label="Label1">
             <c:out value="Text"/>
          </forms:plaintext>
       </forms:row>
        <forms:row>
            <forms:plaintext label="Label2">
                <c:out value="" />
            </forms:plaintext>
        </forms:row>
    </forms:section>
  </forms:form>
</html:form>
```

Comment: So you get the output `Text` twice?

Comment: yes, one under the other

Comment: Hmm, from the source for `<c:out>` I can't see anything that indicates that behavior. Did you check it's not actually the `<forms:plaintext>` tag that handles empty content this way?

Comment: indeed, it's a bug in the <forms:plaintext>. If i use <forms:html> it displays correctly

Comment: I'll add an answer so that others can easily find it whenever they might have a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from the comments on the question: The problem is not the `<c:out>` tag which should work as expected but rather `<forms:plaintext>` which seems to reuse the value of a previous line if its content is empty or whitespace only.